# glibconfig.h no such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, codeblocks, glib

I just installed glib in Raspbian(Debian version). I want to read a config file using glib. I am trying to write a C application in Codeblocks and I use the header

```
#include <glib.h>
```

But I have an error in gtypes.h

```
fatal error:glibconfig.h No such file or directory
```

I used this path

```
project->Build Options->Compiler Settings->Other Options
```

and I added

```
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
```

as I read in [this](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-compiling.html) tutorial. I have to declare also

```
-L/usr/lib -lm -lglib-2.0
```

as the tutorial says and if yes then where and how can I declare it in Codeblocks?

Comment: seems everything ok unless your path are wrong...

Comment: maybe the problem is that I did not declare yet the -L/usr/lib -lm -lglib-2.0 because I don´t know how and where to declare it in Codeblocks

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use `pkg-config`.

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` foo.c `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```

Comment: You can factorize invocation: `gcc foo.c \`pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0\``

Comment: It won't work on Windows. Windows require order of libraries.